# warning messages with constraint at app start

Tags: ios9

when i start my app, (it starts with a table view controller) I get this warning messages in the console. How can i solve it?
I use swift 2 ios 9

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of
>   the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this:
>   (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't
>   expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) (
>   "",
>   "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.
>
> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of
>   the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this:
>   (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't
>   expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or
>   constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) (
>   "",
>   "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved after tapping "update constraints" in all views.

Comment: how can i update constraints ? this option is not active

Comment: You have to select each view and then you can update them